# Extract location name from string SQL

Tags: sql

I want to know is there a way to extract location name from a given string ?
e.g. 
string = 'Las Vegas parties at weekends' or 'Paris fashion updates'
from both string i want out put as: 'Las Vegas' or 'Paris'

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a table which contains the predefined locations?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: +1; I doubt that something like this would even be possible without a reference-table! XD

Comment: Oh wait: There might be a very messy way with **RegEx** looking for Words starting with Upper-Case letters (could work for English language Strings at least), but it would be very error-prone...

Comment: Yes i have a predefined locations table - but what if i want result in single line like = 'Paris Auckland' (from your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a table containing a list of locations (e.g. `locations (name varchar(100))`), you can do something like:

```
select name from locations where @input like '%'+name+'%'
```

Where `@input` is your input string ('Paris fashion updates', etc).

[Here is a working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e21586/1).

By the way, if you are using SQL Server, here is a trick to get the output in a single string without a `while` loop:

```
select @output = @output + ' ' + name 
from locations where @input like '%'+name+'%'
```

See the [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e21586/2).

Comment: Thanks - but what if my string contains more than one location may be a string like 'Paris and London fashion weeks'

Comment: Yes i have a table with predefined locations table

Comment: Yes i have a predefined locations table - but what if i want result in single line like = 'Paris Auckland' (from your code)

Comment: Thanks for the help 'Blorgbeard' i have found the solution by using  while loop and storing value in a variable.

Comment: @user467710 glad I could help, and good to hear you figured it out. See my edit for another possible solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with the predefined locations:

```
CREATE TABLE locations 
  ( 
     [name] VARCHAR(50) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO locations 
            ([name]) 
VALUES      ('Paris'), 
            ('Las Vegas'), 
            ('London'); 

CREATE TABLE [test] 
  ( 
     [input] VARCHAR(max) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO [test] 
            (input) 
VALUES      ('Las Vegas parties at weekends'), 
            ('Paris fashion updates'), 
            ('Paris and London fashion weeks')
```

And then join it with the input strings table:

```
SELECT
    t.Input,
    l.Name
FROM 
    Locations AS l
INNER JOIN test AS t ON t.Input LIKE '%' + l.Name + '%'
ORDER BY
    t.Input
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91dcb/1).